# Usage of [usage]

Tags: support, retag-request, tagging

Our top-rated tag is [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage). However this tag is nearly useless: the word *usage* is right there in the site title, and almost every question on the site could be construed to be about "usage" in some sense. I manually retagged every question that had *only* the [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) tag, but this spammed the Active Questions page, so I'm appealing for mod/dev assistance in cutting down the rest of them.

For many questions that have [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) with some other tags, the [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) tag can be removed without any loss of information in the question. Here's some examples:

- [When is the present perfect tense used instead of the past tense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/present-perfect-tense-versus-past-tense)
- [Possessive of a word that is already possessive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/possessive-of-a-word-thats-already-possessive)
- ["User accounts" or "users account"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/user-accounts-or-users-account)
- [Should I say 'What I wanted to say is' or 'What I wanted to say was'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4411/should-i-say-what-i-wanted-to-say-is-or-what-i-wanted-to-say-was)

These are fine questions with good tags -- but they all have [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) added to them for no good reason. Therefore, I suggest that **all questions with 3 or more tags that include the [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) tag simply be stripped of [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage)**. I looked through several pages of [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) questions and didn't find any cases where this made the question worse or where the [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) tag was adding any useful information.

This should knock [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) out of the top spot and hopefully break the precedent of adding [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) to almost everything. The remaining [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) questions will need to be retagged by hand, in small batches to avoid too much activity spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the tag was removed.

There is one [untagged](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) question now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the two big tags here would be [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) and [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning). As in, "How do I use this?" and "What does this mean?" I do agree that the sheer amount of [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) tags is ridiculous but I am unconvinced that it wouldn't be a useful tag if used properly.

In other news, I am fully willing to help manually retag stuff. If [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) is next on the chopping block I will start hacking away.

EDIT: The comments here clarified my confusion; I agree, [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) is (or should be) completely redundant.

Comment: I have no problem with [meaning], since there often isn't anything better for it. But [usage] is almost anything -- it's like [english] or [question].

Comment: Generally speaking, questions about meaning are not questions about usage... or am I missing something? I guess I could see a parallel between [usage] and [grammar] or [grammaticality].

Comment: What I mean is that [meaning] usually can't be replaced with anything much more specific. [usage], however, should often be retagged [word-choice] or [grammaticality] or [differences] or any number of other things. The umbrella term [usage] is *too broad*.

Comment: @JSBangs: Ah, got it.